# Calling JQuery method on body load condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In php application add new data and modifying exist data on same page, there is radio buttons for select yes or no but it is working perfectly it call

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="yes"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".buttn").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="no"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".buttn").show();
        }
     });
  });

});
```

above method, but for modification on page load i want pass value to above method based on DB table value. like on body tag calling particular JS method.

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand you well, you just have to modify your code to be some custom function,, not jquery on body load.. try this:

```
$.fn.myfunc = function(){

    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="yes"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".buttn").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="no"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".buttn").show();
        }
     });
  });

};
```

and when you pull content from database after that you just call it with:

$.fn.myfunc()

If you need to pass some variables you can do that

$.fn.myfunc( var1, var2 )  but you need to modify your function appropriately

hth

Answer (score 0):

You can do this during generation of your HTML page. Generally, it depends on a templating engine you are using. But, with regular PHP it could be something like this:

```
<?php
$boxClass = 'box';
$btnClass = 'buttn';
if ($valueFromDb == 'yes') {
  $boxClass .= ' hidden';
} else {
  $btnShow .= ' hidden';
}
?>
<!-- some HTML code -->
<div class="<?= $boxClass; ?>">Here is a box</div>
<div class="<?= $btnClass; ?>">Here is a button</div>
```

And define that `.hidden` CSS class as `.hidden { display: none; }`. Going this way, you'll be able to hide all needed block initially without JS.

UPD: Also, instead of generating classes inside that `if` condition, you can render entire HTML blocks like this:

```
<?php if ($someValue == true) { ?>

<!-- render first HTML block -->

<?php } else { ?>

<!-- render another HTML block -->

<?php } ?>
```

This way may be even more appropriate.